Toggle maximize window with autohotkey
How can I make a script to toggle between Maximize/Restore for the current (active) window in autohotkey?
e.g. like this, but toggle:
#x::WinMaximize, A


After some experimenting, I found something that works, this binds it to WinKey+X:
#x::
    WinGet, windowState, MinMax, A
    if (windowState = 1) {
        WinRestore, A
    } else {
        WinMaximize, A
    }
return

